# Trigger something when a catalog price rule is getting active/inactive

Tags: event-observer, catalog-price-rules, price-rules

Basically, I need a way to find out when a price rule gets active/inactive, and which products that is being effected by it. Both when it's made manually, and per the date set in the rule.

I've tried using `catalogrule_after_apply` but I can't get any relevant data out of it.

Any suggestions?

**Edit**:

I've pretty much been fiddling around, dumping data:

```
<catalogrule_after_apply>
    <observers>
        <my_module_catalogrule_after_apply>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>My_Module_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>catalogruleProductApiUpdate</method>
        </my_module_catalogrule_after_apply>
    </observers>
</catalogrule_after_apply>
```

and

```
class My_Module_Model_Observer
{
    public function catalogruleProductApiUpdate (Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        Mage::log('crPAU ran:' . print_r($product, true));
    }
}
```

and similar stuff - just haven't found anything of relevance. I've used `catalog_product_save_commit_after` and `catalog_product_attribute_update_before` with success.

On a sidenote it also runs everytime i save a product - regardless of said product having a price rule or not - and then it prints out the product ID in the log.

I'm a bit unsure about this even being the right event to trigger on.

Comment: Paste what you've tried so far.

Comment: Edited the original post - I've only tried some var dumping and stuff - without finding anything. (to log file, and just plain `die(var_dump($something))`;

Comment: Might have found a solution in hooking into the catalogrule_affected_product table...

Comment: Hooked into the catalogrule_affected_product table - but does not get anything out of it. Actually, when logging the SQL queries, it only ever logs a DELETE query on the table, except from the SELECT query which is in my module. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code may not solve exactly what you're end goal is, but it will hopefully show you how to derive some information out of the catalogrule tables.

My goal was to populate a product's attribute value with either Yes or No depending on whether or not a given product was currently being affected by the Catalog Price Rules, (for use in the Enterprise Visual Merchandiser.)

This works on Magento EE 1.14 but should work on modern Magento CE as well:

```
public function hookCatalogruleAfterApply(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

    if ($product) {
        $this->updateAnyCprAppliedSingle($product);
    } else {
        $this->updateAnyCprAppliedMany();
    }
}

protected function updateAnyCprAppliedSingle($product_id) {
    /*
     * DB Setup
     */
    $resource       = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
    $crp            = $resource->getTableName('catalogrule_product');

    $sql = <<<SQL
        SELECT DISTINCT crp.product_id FROM {$crp} crp
        WHERE crp.product_id = '{$product_id}'
SQL;

    $productRuleStatus = $readConnection->fetchRow($sql);

    $actionModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_action');

    if (!empty($productRuleStatus)) {
        $actionModel->updateAttributes(
            array($product_id),
            array('any_cpr_applied' => 1),
            0
        );
    } else {
        $actionModel->updateAttributes(
            array($product_id),
            array('any_cpr_applied' => 0),
            0
        );
    }
}

protected function updateAnyCprAppliedMany() {
    /*
     * DB Setup
     */
    $resource       = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
    $cpe            = $resource->getTableName('catalog_product_entity');
    $crp            = $resource->getTableName('catalogrule_product');

    $sql = <<<SQL
        SELECT DISTINCT cpe.entity_id, IF(crp.product_id IS NULL, 0, 1) as applied
        FROM {$cpe} cpe
        LEFT JOIN {$crp} crp
        ON cpe.entity_id = crp.product_id
SQL;

    $productRuleStatuses = $readConnection->fetchAll($sql);

    if (!empty($productRuleStatuses)) {
        $actionModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_action');

        $yes = array();
        $no  = array();

        foreach ($productRuleStatuses as $productRuleStatus) {
            if ($productRuleStatus['applied'] == 1) {
                $yes[] = $productRuleStatus['entity_id'];
            } else {
                $no[] = $productRuleStatus['entity_id'];
            }
        }

        if (!empty($yes)) {
            $actionModel->updateAttributes(
                array_values($yes),
                array('any_cpr_applied' => 1),
                0
            );
        }

        if (!empty($no)) {
            $actionModel->updateAttributes(
                array_values($no),
                array('any_cpr_applied' => 0),
                0
            );
        }
    }
}
```

I purposefully named this "any_cpr_applied" because this doesn't take website or customer group into consideration. If you need finer details on which website the product is affected on, which customer group the product affected for, or how the product is affected, you'll need to join more tables.

A quick note on my direct table queries. You can totally replace this with use of the Magento models, however, I was trying to develop this quickly and just made sure I had the dynamic table names.

Comment: Thanks! Does this run on catalogrule_after_apply? If I understand correctly - when there are multiple products (when a rule is applied), it goes through ALL products and sets the attribute to yes/no, right? The issue with that is that I really don't know which products has "changed" - I need to also know the products that were effected that no longer are. But - the attribute way of doing it gave me an idea: checking for when the attribute is changed.

Comment: Yes, it does run on `catalogrule_after_apply` and yes it's resetting the attribute for ALL products. (I ended up making it detect only a change to yes/no using the previous attribute values, as even `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Action` isn't fast enough to change 50,000 products quickly.) As I said, it doesn't give you details on store or customer group or which rule affected which product, but it's a start.

Comment: This might be a solution: 1. Load all product IDs with any_cpr_applied = yes into an array (called $oldYes) 2. run the query in your post and populate the $yes array. 3. $diff1 = array_diff(array_values($oldYes), array_values($yes)); $diff2 = array_diff(array_values($yes), array_values($oldYes)); $changedProductIds = array_merge($diff1, $diff2); I'll now have all product IDs which have changed status in $changedProductIds. This could probably also be used to only update the any_cpr_applied attribute on the effected products - perhaps using array_intersect on $yes/no and $changedProductIds.

Comment: That's basically what my final code did. Good luck!